# I am getting an error in typecasting, please help me out with this

Tags: c++, class, object

Create a class Rectangle. This class has attributes length and width each of which defaults to 1. It has methods that calculate the perimeter and area of the rectangle. It has set and get methods for both length and width. The set methods should verify that length and width are floating – point nos larger than 0.0 and less than 20.0.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class rect
{
    float l;
    float w;
    public:
    void setlw();
    float getl(float len);
    float getw(float width);
    void seta();
    void setp();
};
void rect:: setlw()
{
    cout<<"enter the lenght and width"<<endl;
    cin>>l>>w;
}
float rect:: getl(float len)
{
    if (l>=0.0 && l<=20.0)
    len=l;
    else 
    len=1.0;
    return(len);
}
float rect:: getw(float width)
{
    if(w>=0 && w<=20.0)
    width=w;
    else
    width=1.0;
    return(width);
}
void rect::seta()
{
    float a;
    a=l*w;
    cout<<"the area is"<<a<<endl;
}
void rect:: setp()
{
    float p;
    p=2*(l+w);
    cout<<"the perimeter is"<<p<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    rect r;
    r.setlw();
    cout<<"length is"<<r.getl(float)<<endl;
    cout<<"width is"<<r.getw(float)<<endl;
    r.seta();
    r.setp();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: What is `r.getl(float)` supposed to do?

Comment: Also, do I understand right that `getl` and `getw` are supposed to return the value *and* save it into the passed parameter? In that case, you need to pass the parameter by reference (`float getw(float & out)`)

Comment: Read the instructions. They do not say that you should have a function that prompts the user for values, and they do not say that any of the functions should print anything. And you're mixing up "getting" and "setting".

Comment: Can someone pls help me with the coding of this question

Comment: im a beginner with c++

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code. Removed the input parameters for `getl()` and `getw()`, as it's not required when you are taking input with `setlw()` . You've also not declared variables `len` and `width` in functions `getl` and `getw`.

New Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class rect
{
    float l;
    float w;
    public:
    void setlw();
    float getl();
    float getw();
    void seta();
    void setp();
};
void rect::setlw()
{
    cout<<"enter the lenght and width"<<endl;
    cin>>l>>w;
}
float rect::getl()
{   float len;
    if (l>=0.0 && l<=20.0)
         len=l;
    else 
         len=1.0;
    return(len);
}
float rect::getw()
{   float width;
    if(w>=0 && w<=20.0)
         width=w;
    else
         width=1.0;
    return(width);
}
void rect::seta()
{
    float a;
    a=l*w;
    cout<<"the area is"<<a<<endl;
}
void rect::setp()
{
    float p;
    p=2*(l+w);
    cout<<"the perimeter is"<<p<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    rect r;
    r.setlw();
    cout<<"length is"<<r.getl()<<endl;
    cout<<"width is"<<r.getw()<<endl;
    r.seta();
    r.setp();
    return (0);
}
```